# I need to solve the system of ordinary linear differential equations (Classical Zeeman & Lorentz effect)

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, physics

### Classical Zeeman & Lorentz effect

Stationary homogeneous magnetic field is directed along one axis ($OZ$) 
 An atom is a classical harmonic oscillator, then the Lagrangian for an electron will take the following form $$\mathcal{L}=T-U+V=\frac{m\dot{r}^2}{2}-\frac{kr^2}{2}+e(\vec{A} , \vec{\dot{r}})$$ 
 Using the Euler-Lagrange equation $$\frac{d}{dt}\frac{\partial\mathcal{L}}{\partial \dot{x_i}}-\frac{\partial\mathcal{L}}{\partial x_i}=0,$$ 
 We obtain a system of ODLE $$ \ddot{x}(t)+\omega_0^2 x - \omega_H \dot{y}(t)=0$$ 
$$\ddot{y}(t)+\omega_0^2 y + \omega_H \dot{x}(t)=0 $$ 
$$\ddot{z}(t)+\omega_0^2z=0$$

 I need to solve the first two, because third is independent of them. I've tried to differentiate the first and put in the second, but unsuccessfully

Comment: Yes, they are constant

Comment: Hint: $\zeta:=x+iy$ satisfies the ODE $\ddot{\zeta}+i\omega_H\dot{\zeta}+\omega_0^2\zeta=0$.

Comment: Interesting, i will think. Thanks.

Comment: @Gonçalo If I get a decision for $\xi$, what should I do next? Am I just supposed to get two orthogonal solutions by relating the real and imaginary parts?

Comment: Solve the ODE for $\zeta$ with initial conditions $\zeta(0)=x(0)+iy(0)$ and $\dot{\zeta}(0)=\dot{x}(0)+i\dot{y}(0)$; then $x(t)=\Re(\zeta(t))$ and $y(t)=\Im(\zeta(t))$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From

$$ \ddot{x}(t)+\omega_0^2 x - \omega_H \dot{y}(t)=0$$ 
$$\ddot{y}(t)+\omega_0^2 y + \omega_H \dot{x}(t)=0 $$

we obtain

$$ \ddot{x}(t)\dot x(t)+\omega_0^2 x \dot x - \omega_H \dot{y}(t)\dot x(t)=0$$ 
$$\ddot{y}(t)\dot y(t)+\omega_0^2 y\dot y + \omega_H \dot{x}(t)\dot y(t)=0 $$

and after addition

$$
\frac 12(\dot x^2+\dot y^2)'+\frac 12\omega_0^2(x^2+y^2)'=0
$$

obtaining a movement constant

$$
(\dot x^2+\dot y^2)+\omega_0^2(x^2+y^2)=C
$$

Also applying the Laplace transform

$$
s^2\hat x(s) +\omega_0^2\hat x(s)-\omega_H s\hat y(s) = s x(0) + \dot x(0) - \omega_H y(0)\\
s^2\hat y(s) +\omega_0^2\hat y(s)+\omega_H s\hat x(s) = s y(0) + \dot y(0) + \omega_H x(0)\\
$$

or

$$
\cases{
\hat x(s) = \frac{\phi_1(s) \left(\omega_0 ^2+s^2\right)+\omega_H\phi_2(s) s}{\omega_0^4+s^2 \left(2 \omega_0 ^2+\omega_H^2\right)+s^4}\\
\hat y(s) = \frac{\phi_2(s) \left(\omega_0 ^2+s^2\right)-\omega_H\phi_1(s) s}{\omega_0^4+s^2 \left(2 \omega_0 ^2+\omega_H^2\right)+s^4}
}
$$

with $\phi_1(s) = s x(0) + \dot x(0) - \omega_H y(0),\ \ \phi_2(s) = s y(0) + \dot y(0) + \omega_H x(0)$ easily invertible.

Comment: Hmm, interesting. Have you applied Laplace transform on initial equations?
And the first way actually does not solve problem...Or i didn't understand...
Finally you got images of $x$ and $y$, is it possible to use inverse Laplace transform, I mean it is very complicated term? (I'm not too strong yet in this)
I know that approximate answer must be kind of $x(t) = Ae^{i\lambda_1 t} + Be^{-i\lambda_1 t} + Ce^{i\lambda_2 t} + De^{-i\lambda_2 t}.$ Apparently lambdas are roots of some characteristic equation. Is it possible to get this form?

Comment: Calling $\Omega^2 = 2 \omega_0^2+\omega_H^2$ and solving $\omega_0^4+\Omega^2 s^2+s^4=0$ we have that $\lambda_1 = \frac{\sqrt{\Omega^2+\sqrt{\Omega^4-4 \omega_0^4}}}{\sqrt{2}}$ and $\lambda_2 = \frac{\sqrt{\Omega^2-\sqrt{\Omega^4-4 \omega_0^4}}}{\sqrt{2}}$

Comment: Basically this solves the problem, thanks. There it really turns out something like the sums of the exponent. But in the comments to the question, I think I noticed an interesting hint, perhaps with a more elegant (short) solution